# Reference detection in array from another function

Tags: php, arrays, loops, reference

So I'm using the pin method, but the reference is detected one level too late:

```
$pin = time();

function wrap($arr){
  test($arr);
}

function test(&$arr){
    global $pin;

    if(in_array($pin, $arr))
        return print "ref";

    $arr[] = $pin;

    foreach($arr as &$v){

        if($v != $pin){

            if(is_array($v))
                return test($v);

            print $v . " ";

      }

    }

}

$array = array(1, 2, 3);
$array[4] = &$array;

wrap($array);
```

I get `1 2 3 1 2 3 rec`

But I expect `1 2 3 rec`

If I just do `test($arr)` then it works, but the problem is that I need to wrap the test function inside another one that accepts values not references :(

Is there any way I can detect the reference at the right moment with my wrapper function too?

Comment: `$pin` never changes, is that intentional?

Comment: yes. it's supposed to be used to compare if two arrays are the same variable..

Comment: @Alex autodetect? I don't think so, only: `function wrap(&$arr)`.

Comment: Short answer: no. As soon as you pass the input by value, the internal reference is no longer to the passed structure, it's to the original external one. The only way this is possible is to pass by reference, if you do that then I refer you to my [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11545201/889949) on the subject of detecting whether two given variables are references to each other.

Comment: you could just alter the call to `wrap`, like: `wrap(array(&$array))[0]` (php v5.4!)

Comment: I would scrap the whole method as rewrite it, there's so many things wrong with that :)

Comment: @Alex please consider my update. Read **UPDv1** bottom part.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Introduction**

I think a better approach would be to create a copy of the array and compare modification rather than use global pin and it can still be a `100% Recursive`

**Example 1**

This is from your example above :

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$array[4] = &$array;
wrap($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [4] => ref
)
```

**Example 2**

Are we really sure its detecting reference or just a copy of the array

```
//Case 1 : Expect no modification
$array = array(1, 2, 3, array(1, 2, 3));
wrap( $array);

//Case 2 : Expect Modification in Key 2
$array = array(1, 2, 3, array(1, 2, 3));
$array[2] = &$array;
wrap( $array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => ref
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

**Example 3**

Is this really recursive ?

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, array(1, 2, 3));
$array[4][4][2][6][1] = array(1,2,3=>&$array);
wrap( $array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1
                                            [1] => 2
                                            [3] => ref   <-- GOT YOU
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Your Modified Function**

```
/**
 * Added printf since test now returns array
 * @param array $arr
 */
function wrap(array $arr) {
    printf("<pre>%s<pre>", print_r(test($arr), true));
}


/**
 * - Removed Top Refrence
 * - Removed Global
 * - Add Recursion
 * - Returns array
 * @param array $arr
 * @return array
 */
function test(array $arr) {
    $temp = $arr;
    foreach ( $arr as $key => &$v ) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $temp[$key]['_PIN_'] = true;
            $v = isset($arr[$key]['_PIN_']) ? "ref" : test($v);
        }
    }
    unset($temp); // cleanup
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are over-complicating things. I solved this by looping over the array and checking if the current value in the array is equivalent (`===`) with the array.

```
function wrap( $arr){
    test($arr);
}

function test( $arr){
    foreach( $arr as $v) {
        if( $v === $arr) { 
            print 'ref, ';
        } else {
            if( is_array( $v)) { 
                test( $v); 
            } else {
                print $v . ', ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the following test cases:

```
echo "Array 1:\n";
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$array1[4] = &$array1;
wrap( $array1);

echo "\nArray 2:\n";
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, array(1, 2, 3));
$array2[2] = &$array2;
wrap( $array2);
```

Which [produced this output](http://viper-7.com/riQjk6):

```
Array 1: 
1, 2, 3, ref 
Array 2: 
1, 2, ref, 1, 2, 3,
```

However, the above method will fail for nested references. If nested references are possible, as in the following test case:

```
echo "\nArray 3:\n";
$array3 = array(1, 2, 3, array(1, 2, 3));
$array3[3][2] = &$array3;
wrap( $array3);
```

Then we need to keep track of all the array references we've seen, like this:

```
function wrap( $arr){
    test( $arr);
}

function test( $arr){
    $refs = array(); // Array of references that we've seen

    $f = function( $arr) use( &$refs, &$f) {
        $refs[] = $arr;
        foreach( $arr as $v) {
            if( in_array( $v, $refs)) { 
                print 'ref, ';
            } else {
                if( is_array( $v)) {
                    $f( $v); 
                } else {
                    print $v . ', ';
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $f( $arr);
}
```

Using the above test case, this outputs:

```
Array 3: 
1, 2, 3, 1, ref, 3,
```

**Edit:** I've updated the final function that keeps track of all references to eliminate the global dependencies.

Comment: it's not supposed to return after the reference. it should just print 'ref' and continue to the next element...

Comment: @Alex - I've updated my answer and cleaned up the comments on this post. Please let me know if it does not perform how you expect.

Comment: your solution is still producing false-positives for arrays such as: `$array = array(1, 2, array(1, 2), array(1, 2));`. By the way, I saw what you did there. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi - Crap, was afraid of that. But since you made such a compelling argument against global variables, I had to refactor them out. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
function wrap($arr){ test($arr); }
/// ...
wrap($array);
```

Your `wrap()` function allocates new memory block for `$arr`. When you calling `test()` function within `wrap()`s body, it takes reference of `$arr` memory block, but not an `$array`s memory block, because `$arr` ***is a copy*** of `$array` and PHP memory management system *stores them separately*.

---

There is a universal reference spotting function:

```
function is_equal_refs(&$a, &$b){
    $buffer = $a;          // saving current value in temporary variable

    $a = md5(time());      // assigning new value to memory block, pointed by reference

    $result = ($a === $b); // if they're still equal, then they're point to the same place.

    $a = $buffer;          // restoring value

    return $result;        // returning result
}
```

So, lets do some testing:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function is_equal_refs(&$a, &$b){
    $buffer = $a;

    $a = md5(time());

    $result = ($a === $b);

    $a = $buffer;

    return $result;
}

function wrap($arr){ test($arr); }

function test(&$arr){
    foreach($arr as &$v){

        if(is_equal_refs($arr, $v)){
            print_r('ref');
            echo PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }

        if(is_array($v))return test($v);

        print_r($v);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$array   = array(1, 2, 3);
$array[] = &$array;

wrap($array);
?>
```

Shows:

```
1   // < $arr
2
3
1   // < $array
2
3
ref // < $array doubled -> reference found
```

The reason of such behavior is `$arr[3]` contains reference for `$array`s memory block, but not reference of itself's memory block.

Lets remove a `$array[] = &$array;` row, and modify `wrap()` function to check:

```
function wrap($arr){
    $arr[] = &$arr;

    test($arr);
}
```

And result would be:

```
1   // < $arr
2
3
ref // < $arr doubled -> reference found
```

Because `$arr` not points to `$array`, but to itself in `$arr[3]`. So, in your code there are different references you want to spot.

---

**CONCLUSION:** What you want to achieve is breaking out PHP memory management rules.

---

**UPDv1:**

Need to seek a **workaround**, to restore `$array` reference in a `wrap()` function scope.

*1) A "**bad**" / "**globals**" practice:*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function is_equal_refs(&$a, &$b){
    $buffer = $a;

    $a = md5(time());

    $result = ($a === $b);

    $a = $buffer;

    return $result;
}

function wrap($array){
    global $check; // <- THIS

    test(empty($check) ? $array : $check); // <- THIS
}

function test(&$arr){
    foreach($arr as &$v){

        if(is_equal_refs($v, $arr)){
            print_r('ref');
            echo PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }

        if(is_array($v)){
            test($v);
        } else {
            print $v . ' ';
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

$array   = array(1, 2, 3);
$array[] = &$array;
$check   = &$array; // <- and THIS

wrap($array);
?>
```

Which shows:

```
1
2
3
ref
```

---

*2) A "**wrap everything in array or object**" practice:* (prefered and reliable)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

define('REF_MARKER', 'x-my-tr!cky-ref'); // trick key definition

function is_equal_refs(&$a, &$b){
        $buffer = $a;

        $a = md5(time());

        $result = ($a === $b);

        $a = $buffer;

        return $result;
    }

function wrap(array $arr){
        // restore reference, if trick.
        // it might be moved to the top part of test() function (might affect performance).
        if(isset($arr[REF_MARKER]))$arr = &$arr[REF_MARKER];

        test($arr);
    }

// $array - subject to test;
// $refs  - internal ref list of all `subjects`;
function test(&$array, $refs = array()){
        $refs[] = &$array;

        foreach($array as &$value){

            foreach($refs as &$ref){
                if(is_equal_refs($ref, $value))return print 'ref ';
            }

            if(is_array($value)){
                $refs[] = &$value;

                test($value, $refs);
            } else {
                print $value . ' ';
            }
        }
    }

$array   = array(1, 2, 3);
$array[] = &$array;

wrap(array(REF_MARKER => &$array)); // trick

print PHP_EOL;

$ring      = array(1, 2, 3, array(4, 5, 6));
$ring[3][] = &$ring;

wrap(array(REF_MARKER => &$ring)); // trick

print PHP_EOL;

$test = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$ring = array(1, 2, 3);

$ring[] = &$test;
$test[] = &$ring;

wrap(array(REF_MARKER => &$ring)); // trick

print PHP_EOL;

wrap(range(1, 5)); // normal

print PHP_EOL;

$test = array(1, 2, 3, array(1, 2, 3), 4, array(5, 2, 3), array(6, array(1, 2, 3), 7), array(1, 2, 3));

wrap($test); // normal

print PHP_EOL;

$test[]    = &$test;
$test[3][] = &$test;
$test[5][] = &$test[3];

wrap(array(REF_MARKER => &$test)); // trick
?>
```

Shows:

```
1 2 3 ref
1 2 3 4 5 6 ref
1 2 3 a b c ref
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 6 1 2 3 7 1 2 3
1 2 3 1 2 3 ref 4 5 2 3 ref 6 1 2 3 7 1 2 3 ref
```